# ImportError: cannot import name redirect_stderr

Tags: python

I think this somehow related to installed Python, but I have no clue how to fix it.

This is what I have:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12

$ pyftsubset
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pyftsubset", line 7, in <module>
    from fontTools.subset import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fontTools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fontTools.misc.py23 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fontTools/misc/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from fontTools.misc.py23 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fontTools/misc/py23.py", line 6, in <module>
    from contextlib import redirect_stderr, redirect_stdout
ImportError: cannot import name redirect_stderr
```

Comment: Which version of `fontTools` are you using?

Comment: `redirect_stdout` is available from Python 3.4 onwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in incorrect version of Python:

https://pypi.org/project/fonttools/

> FontTools 4.x requires Python 3.6 or later. FontTools 3.x requires Python 2.7 or later.

I tried to use latest **fonttools** with Python 2. Installing Python 3 with reinstallation of **fonttools** solved the issue:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install -y python3 python-pip
pip install --upgrade pip
hash -r
pip install fonttools
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to uninstall `fontTools` and then install the [py27](https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools/tree/py27) branch of it. The version you are using isn't backwards compatible to Python 2.7